# Randomly redirect with PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I'm trying to redirect 2 URL randomly but it not working.

My Code

```php
<?php
$urls=readStack();
if(empty($urls)) {
    $urls = shuffle(array('https://domain1.com', 'https://domain2.com')); 
    $url=array_pop($urls);
    storeStack($urls);
    header('Location:' .$url); 
?>
```

Help how to fix this?

Comment: Read up on ‘shuffle’ it doesn’t return a shuffled array.

Comment: Also have a normal array and use a random  0 or 1

Comment: Also you have a parse error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `readStack()` and `storeStack()` are but you probably want something like

```
$arr = array('https://domain1.com', 'https://domain2.com');
shuffle($arr); // This returns a boolean and the array is modified inside the function so just pass in the array
$url=array_pop($arr); // Pop the top most element from the array and store into $url
header("Location: $url");
```

That code alone gives you a random url from those two